# Compositing: scale without cropping?

Tags: compositing-nodes

In Compositing, picture scaling leads to image cropping, is it possible to avoid? After that I also apply translating, so my final result fits usual render output size, but during the processing I want to be able to keep higher dimensions.

I only googled out this: https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/35425 which says it's a planned feature, but that was 10 years ago, I hope it's doable now

PS: I need to scale X & Y differently and dynamically, so I can't just zoom the camera.